Is it true that $tr(APA^T)$ > $tr(AQA^T)$, if $tr(P)$ > $tr(Q)$
Assuming $P$ and $Q$ and positive definite matrix.
Is it true that $tr(APA^T)$ > $tr(AQA^T)$, when $tr(P)$ > $tr(Q)$. [EDIT after first answer: not just that, actually $P_{ii} > Q_{ii} $ for all $i$] Here tr() means the trace of the matrix.
I have tried a new matrixes and I think the answer is yes, but I am not sure how to prove it

This pair added after question edit.
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
20 & 19 \\ 
19 & 20 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
101 & -100 \\ 
-100 & 101 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
20 & 19 \\ 
19 & 20 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
861 & 660 \\ 
660 & 861 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
20 & 19 \\ 
19 & 20 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
20 & 19 \\ 
19 & 20 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1522 & 1520 \\ 
1520 & 1522 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 13 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 13 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
24 & 0 \\ 
0 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

sorry Will, I added another edit to my question .. I wasn't clear. Actually $P_{ii} > Q_{ii} $ for all $i$

Can I ask how did you come up with the examples so quickly? What kind of "intuition" was behind the examples
